# How to construct high-dimensional variable in R?

Tags: statistics, programming

How to construct high-dimensional variable in R?

For example;
Consider the situation where we may want to explain each response variable $Y \in \mathbb{R}$ by a $p$-dimensional variable $X \sim \text{Unif}([0,1]^p)$.
What is the R code of constructing $X$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to notice is that $X \sim Unif([0,1]^p)$ if $X_i \sim Unif([0,1])$ where $X_i$ is the $i$-th coordinate of $X$ and those $X_i$ are i.i.d. Then you can generate $X$ by typing $\texttt{runif(p)}$ ([see the reference](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/Uniform)).

Comment: Since I have been given p and n in this case. If p = 2, n = 100. Should it be
x = rep(runif(100), times =2 )?

Comment: You can just make an array of arrays. Set $\texttt{sample = c()}$ and then iterate $n$ times the command $\texttt{sample = c(sample, runif(p))}$.

Comment: Or you can do $\texttt{sample = matrix(runif(n*p), nrow = n, ncol = p)}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!